# File's Owner is not responding?

Tags: interface-builder

I'm creating app, using IB. But File's Owner doesn't want to work! I can't see, what in it, can't drag line to code from buttons in IB. 
In code, all's okay. Connection with First Responder is wokrs nice, but it isn't that i want.

For example, now i can't connect UIButton with it's IBOutlet, cauze, when I drag line to code from button, there are nothing happens.

What's the problem?

Thx,
Maxim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the file's owner's class in IB:

1. Select the file's owner (by clicking on it)
2. In the utilities area open the "Identity Inspector".
3. Set the topmost field "Custom Class" to your file's owner's class.

Comment: Custom class? I have a right class in it (Class with .H and .M of this XIB file). Or i didn't understood you?

P.S: Thx 4 answer!

Comment: Hm? What u can say about it? 

@NikolaiRuhe